# Paremeters in TableAdapter not accepted

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, parameters, syntax-error, tableadapter

I'm currently trying to set up my TableAdapters, but it doesn't allow me to use parameters (what makes it quite useless) - When I create a new Query

```
SELECT     users.*
FROM         users
WHERE name LIKE @name
```

It tells me there is a SQL-Error near `'@'`...

I'm using VS08 with C# and an Access-Database using OleDB-Driver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look here:

[How to: Create Parameterized TableAdapter Queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171905%28VS.90%29.aspx)

> When constructing a parameterized
>   query, use the parameter notation
>   specific to the database you are
>   coding against. For example, Access
>   and OleDb data sources use the
>   question mark '?' to denote
>   parameters, so the WHERE clause would
>   look like this: WHERE City = ?.

Try to substitute @ with ? and see if your query compiles.

Comment: Well okay, explains a lot... I used to use MSSQL-Databases and was used to the `@` - thanks a bunch.