# Access Query With Parameters in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, vb.net, ms-access, visual-studio-2010, ms-access-2007

Microsoft Access queries with `somecolumnname = [?]` do not show up in the list of Views in the New DataSource Wizard in Visual Studio.

The query works perfectly from within Microsoft Access by just prompting for the values of the parameters.

The columns of the query should populate labels on my form based on the values in a couple textboxes.

What is the "best-practices" way to use parameter queries in my .NET application?

**Note:** If applicable, VB.NET answers preferred over C# (both acceptable).

Comment: Could you all please check this question.. its somewhat similar.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27916036/how-to-access-parameter-query-in-dataset-from-ms-access-in-visual-studio-2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you do this:

```
somecolumnname = ?
```

instead of

```
somecolumnname = [?]
```

Take a look at this:

[Paremeters in TableAdapter not accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316450/paremeters-in-tableadapter-not-accepted/3316491#3316491)

Are you missing some step?

[How to: Connect to Data in an Access Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cf131f6b%28VS.90%29.aspx)

[Walkthrough: Connecting to Data in an Access Database (Windows Forms)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171893.aspx)

Comment: He's trying to access a saved Access query.  It may be exposed as a sproc.

Comment: Is it possible to have a valid saved Access QueryDef with "omecolumnname = ?" in it? Given that "?" is the standard Jet/ACE SQL single-character wildcard (like _ in SQL Server), I don't think it will work.

Comment: I don't know anything about .NET, but an Access parameter query is more like an SPROC than it is like a VIEW. It should not be surprising if they did not show up in a list of VIEWs.

Comment: Your answer directly didn't help.  However, your links pointed me in the right direction.  I just removed the `somecolumnname = ?` from the query in access, added a query to the `TableAdapter`, then added the condition to the newly created `TableAdapter.FillBy` query.

Comment: Good to know the links helped you.

Answer (score -1):

This is based on a little understanding of Access, not of VB.Net, but it may help.

```
    Dim cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand

    Try
        cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
       "Data Source=c:\Docs\Test.mdb;"
        cn.Open()

        cmd.Connection = cn
        ''It is just a query, not a procedure, but this is what
        ''works with Access
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.CommandText = "test"
        With cmd.Parameters
            .AddWithValue("myparam", "SomeVal")
        End With

     <...>
```

OLE DB Providers: http://www.carlprothman.net/Default.aspx?tabid=87#OLEDBProviderForMicrosoftJet