# Created Parameterized query not showing in datasource visual studio 10 and access

Tags: winforms, dataset, ms-access-2007, datasource

I'm trying to replicate `northwind` database but when I created parameter query **`vw_CustomerOrderYear`**, the query is not showing in my datasource.

 I do not know what I'm missing..

My parameter query `vw_CustomerOrderYear` is :

```
PARAMETERS OrderYear Long;

SELECT DISTINCT Customer.ID, Customer.Name, Customer.City, Customer.Country,
Year([Order].OrderDate) AS OrderYear
FROM Customer INNER JOIN [Order] ON Customer.ID=Order.CustomerId
WHERE (((Year(Order.OrderDate))=[OrderYear])) Or ((([OrderYear]) Is Null));
```

How can I get this query under my `SomeNameDataSet` ?

Comment: What i did was i created the same parameter query as northwind in my database. But its not showing in my datasource dataset.

Comment: Can you get **any** query to appear as a datasource?

Comment: yes.. queries without parameters are shown in the dataset. I I created parameterized query in access . Now i'm trying to create it through visual studio 10 . Ive seen few examples in the net which gets parameter query through visual studio

Answer (score 3):

When you create a "parameter query" in the Microsoft Access application itself (MSACCESS.EXE), i.e., one whose SQL code looks like ...

```sql
PARAMETERS ... ; SELECT ... FROM ...
```

... it is considered a "Query" by ACE/Jet DAO (Data Access Objects), which is the technology that MSACCESS uses to communicate with the Access Database Engine (ACE or Jet). You can run the query in Access and get prompted for the parameter values, or you can use a DAO QueryDef object in VBA and pass the parameter values to the .Parameters collection of that QueryDef object.

"Dataset" Data Sources in .NET projects behave differently because they use System.Data.OleDb, and the ACE/Jet OLEDB provider does not classify those queries as "Views". Instead, it classifies them as "[Stored] Procedures". So, if you were to open an OleDbConnection and do

```csharp
DataTable dtViews = con.GetSchema("Views")
```

then the query would not show up in the resulting list. That's why you cannot see it under "Views" in the Data Sources wizard in Visual Studio.

However, it does show up if you do

```csharp
DataTable dtProcedures = con.GetSchema("Procedures")
```

So, you can use the existing Access "parameter query" by treating it like a Stored Procedure in your .NET code, e.g.,

```csharp
using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand())
{
    cmd.Connection = con;  // an open OleDbConnection to the database
    cmd.CommandText = "vw_CustomerOrderYear";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("OrderYear", OleDbType.Integer).Value = 2014;
    using (OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(rdr[0]);
        }
    }
}
```